# What's wrong with my "on delete set default"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm on Postgresql 13.

I want a table(rooms) that assume the default value of "1" if I delete from building which is the "parent table"
This is my sql code

```
DROP TABLE rooms;
DROP TABLE buildings;

CREATE TABLE buildings (
    building_no INT default 1 primary key,
    building_name VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    room_name VARCHAR(255),
    building_no INT default 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no) REFERENCES buildings (building_no) ON DELETE SET default );
```

I insert the values into the tables

```
   insert into buildings values (1,'Building1','Street 33');    
   insert into buildings values (2,'Build-B','Street 34');
   insert into rooms values (1,'Room 1',1);
   insert into rooms values (2,'Room 2',2);
```

Then I delete from buildings

```
delete from buildings;
```

When I delete from buildings instead of make the default value of 1 as I ask it set the value NULL.

```
test=> select * from rooms;
 room_no | room_name | building_no 
---------+-----------+-------------
       1 | Room 1    |            
       2 | Room 2    |
```

What's wrong in my sql code?

Comment: I'm guessing but I don't see how you can delete all the Buildings and expect the Table.building_no to be updated to 1 since there's no Building with this ID (i.e. the set default would violate the foreign key). Maybe try delete just building 2 and see what happens.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get the expected `ERROR:  update or delete on table "buildings" violates foreign key constraint "rooms_building_no_fkey" on table "rooms"` with `DETAIL:  Key (building_no)=(1) is still referenced from table "rooms".`. What version are you using? Is this standard PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, is the standard Postresql  13 on Centos 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By deleting all of the records in buildings, the default value of 1 in the rooms table violates the FK constraint. Therefore, it's going to set it to NULL. If you were to delete all buildings EXCEPT building 1, you will not encounter the behavior you are describing.

Comment: That does not make sense. I would expect an error and would consider everything else a bug. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, see my comment to the question.